# Datastore Read Operations Calculation

Tags: google-app-engine, operations

So I am currently performing a test, to estimate how much can my Google app engine work, without going over quotas.
This is my test:

- I have in the datastore an entity, that according to my local
  dashboard, needs 18 write operations. I have 5 entries of this type
  in a table.
- Every 30 seconds, I fetch those 5 entities mentioned    above. I DO
  NOT USE MEMCACHE FOR THESE !!!

That means 5 * 18 = 90 read operations, per fetch right ?
In 1 minute that means 180, in 1 hour that means 10800 read operations..Which is ~20% of the daily limit quota...

However, after 1 hour of my test running, I noticed on my online dashboard, that only 2% of the read operations were used...and my question is why is that?...Where is the flaw in my calculations ?

Also...where can I see in the online dashboard how many read/write operations does an entity need?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A write on your entity may need 18 **writes**, but a get on your entity will cost you only 1 **read**.

So if you get 5 entries every 30 secondes during one hour, you'll have about 5reads * 120 = 600 reads.

This is in the case you make a **get** on your 5 entries. (fetching the entry with it's id)
If you make a **query** to fetch them, the cost is "1 read + 1 read per entity retrieved". Wich mean 2 reads per entries. So around 1200 reads in one hour.

For more details informations, here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#cost_resource) for estimating costs.

You can't see on the dashboard how many writes/reads operations an entity need. But I invite you to check [appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) for that.

Comment: Ok i think i get...there is one thing that i don't know...lets say i have a table with 1000 entities...and i make a query that needs to retrieve only 5 of them...How many reads will this take?...On the website you gave me there is something like this specified...that i don't understand : Note: Queries that specify an offset are charged for the number of results that are skipped in addition to those that are returned.

Comment: If you do a GQL query with a "WHERE" condition, and this query retrieve 5 entries, the cost is 2 reads per entries. But if you do a GQL query with a "WHERE" and an "OFFSET", the cost is 2 reads per entries you retrieve + 2reads * the number of entries ignored from the offset.

Comment: Why is that OFFSET used ? From what i quickly read, to limit the number of rows returned? What i have in my code is something like this : `cls.all().filter('was_accepted =', true)` ...so basically all the rows with that condition...I am assuming that I am not using OFFSET here right ?

Comment: No, you are not using OFFSET in your code. You are just filtering so that's ok.

Comment: @PatrickDura Is there any way to know which entity is getting read more time in project?